# Magento 2 replace dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension errors with compiler error

Tags: magento2, composer

We have added the following to composer json in M 2.3.5

```
    "replace": {
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
```

Then we run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

And are presented with this error

```
Repositories code generation... 1/8 [===>------------------------]  12% 1 sec 88.5 MiB
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Block\Adminhtml\EngagementCloudEmbedInterface' 
not found in /var/www/html/m2/m2_dev/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat/Block/Adminhtml/StudioChatWidget.php on line 13
```

Question: Is there more we need to do to disable Dotdigital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additional extensions are bundled with Magento 2.3.5. The error you're getting is to do with the chat client module.

You can remove all modules with the following replaces:

```
"dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
"dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
"dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
"dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*",
```

https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-bundled maintains a meta-package that removes third party bundled modules

Comment: After adding this to composer the error is still "Repositories code generation... 1/8 [===>------------------------]  12% 1 sec 92.5 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Block\Adminhtml\EngagementCloudEmbedInterface' not found in /vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat/Block/Adminhtml/StudioChatWidget.php on line 13
"

Comment: Did you run `composer update`?